# 403 calling api.weather.gov using Buzz client w/ https

Tags: php, curl, noaa, buzz

Trying to use curl/file_get_contents using Buzz in my Symfony application to retrieve data like from what you could see here:

https://api.weather.gov/points/44.3537,-73.8636/forecast/hourly

No matter what, I seem to get a 403 Forbidden error and I'm wondering if anyone has any advice?

```
    $location = sprintf(
        '/points/%f,%f/forecast/hourly', $this->latitude, $this->longitude
    );

    $request  = new Request('GET', $location, 'https://api.weather.gov');
    $response = new Response();

    try {
        $this->httpClient->send($request, $response);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new ServiceResponseException('Failed to send Request', 0, $e);
    }

    if (!$response->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ServiceResponseException('Unsuccessful Response', $response->getStatusCode());
    }

    return $response->getContent();
```

In Buzz' FileGetContents class

```
$url = $request->getHost().$request->getResource();
```

$url evaluates to :
https://api.weather.gov/points/44.353700,-73.863600/forecast/hourly

Same with CURL

Headers returned

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden [1] => Server: AkamaiGHost [2] => Mime-Version: 1.0 [3] => Content-Type: text/html [4] => Content-Length: 334 [5] => Expires: Thu, 13 Apr 2017 14:15:56 GMT [6] => Date: Thu, 13 Apr 2017 14:15:56 GMT [7] => Connection: close )
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Sorry @ATechGuy , just added a blurb of what I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Accept`, `Version`, and `User-Agent` headers.